# How would I block OneDrive from syncing a folder?

Tags: onedrive

I have OneDrive set up to sync virtually everything I care about; my downloads, documents, and various media are all set up to save in OneDrive.

However, I've recently worked out that video games tend to use `Documents/My Games/` to store data that they are using, meaning that OneDrive and the game get in a fist fight over who controls them.

I can't just move the folder since I would have to move where every game I play stores their data, and every future game, and most games don't support that.

Is there a way to stop OneDrive from syncing a subfolder while still having that folder accessible locally?

Comment: You can stop synchronizing the Documents folder, and change where you save documents, to a folder within OneDrive root folder. No; There is no way to exclude a child folder within a root folder that is configured to synchronize to   OneDrive

Comment: If you are using OneDrive for business, you may block Syncing of Specific File Types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/block-file-types

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the issue for myself.

You're probably using OneDrive backup. This logically moves your `Documents` folder to `OneDrive/Documents`, and games are using this one.

Unfortunately, you can't get games to save somewhere else, and you can't keep OneDrive from synching all subfolders.
But you can move your games-folders back to the original `Documents` and then deactivate OneDrive backup. This links `%USERDATA%` back to your `Documents` folder, so games find them there. With Cloud-Saving your games are still saved at steam or gog. Whatever is left in `OneDrive/Documents` is still synched on OneDrive.

Your main inconvenience is you now have to manually make sure you save your other files to `OneDrive/Documents`. Luckily most Apps remember this after you did it for the first time.

Comment: Paragraphs are part of a properly formatted breakfast, I mean, answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with *most* subdirectories using [this method](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/the-folder-you-tried-to-unselect-contains-the/70da1720-5d3d-49ff-a114-fcb578b6cb68?LastReply=true#LastReply):

> Easy way around it without stopping the backup is to make a copy of the folder somewhere outside of desktop/documents/pictures and login to OneDrive in the browser to delete said folder from desktop/documents/pictures linked there. Then copy the folder back in to its original location to find OneDrive not syncing it any more.

One minor exception, the much vaunted "`Ny Games`" directory, and its subfolders. Deleting the folder online will remove it everywhere, including the the entries in "Account=>Choose Folders." Recreating it in the local drive automatically re-syncs it to the cloud, and as usual, any subfolder of "`Ny Games`" cannot be deselected. Can be a minor inconvenience if there is a gigabyte of game saves on rig A and a gigabyte of game saves on rig B you don't want on A.

What happened here after turning the backup off, was that various subfolders in Documents could be turned off at ease, including "`My Games`", somehow the latter auto-reselected after restarting the backup.

Having said that, given it has lost time for me, your experience may vary, and be sure to take Ralph Durner's advice and save the games in the Steam or GOG clouds instead.